# What does int *p = (int*) 60 mean?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *p = (int*) 60;    --- Line 1
    int *q = (int*) 40;    --- Line 2
    printf("%d", p-q);    //Output is 5
    return 0;
}
```

Could anybody please explain to me the output of this program?

Comment: `p` is pointer to `int` at 60 bytes from the beginning of the address space. `q` is a pointer to `int` at 40 bytes from the beginning of the address space. Their difference is 20 bytes or `20/sizeof(int) = 5` `int` elements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means the (implementation-defined) action of assigning an integral value to a pointer happens. This often means that `p` points to the memory address at `60` and `q` to the address at `40`. These memory addresses could be in virtual memory, hardware memory, and many implementations have different conversion routines for these.

Since this is implementation-defined anything could happen, as described by your implementation.

### But isn't this entirely worthless?

It's most certainly not, it is used a **lot** in embedded hardware programming to access certain features or call built-in functions.

---

Most likely on your system `int` is 4 bytes wide, so `p - q` equals `(60 - 40) / 4 == 5`.

Comment: Seems predictable; 20/sizeof(int) = 5.

Answer (score 8):

It's making `p` point to the memory address `60` and `q` point to the memory address `40`. Then presumably your architecture has 4-byte `int`s and so `p - q` equals `5` ((60 - 40) / 4).

Answer (score 1):

You're creating two pointer values and then doing pointer math. Apparently `sizeof(int)` on your system is 4 bytes, so the distance between the two pointer values is 5.

Answer (score 1):

Each pointer, `p` and `q`, is a pointer to an int. `p` points to memory address 60, and `q` to memory address 40. When you subtract `q` from `p`, the result is how many 4-byte `int`s fit in-between, in this case 5. that is done to make using pointers with arrays easier, if they were in the same array.

See [this site](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html) for more information about pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

The statement declares a pointer to an integer at address 60

```
int *p = (int*) 60;
```

You probably already know this; The danger of doing this is: how do you know there is actually an integer stored at address 60?

Comment: Then, can we access p and assign a value to it like so? ``*p = 20``

Answer (score 0):

The int pointer initialization is to ensure that the pointer is pointing to the memory address of an integer, in this case memory location 60 and 40 for pointers p and q respectively.

What the output is giving you is the difference in memory locations. Usually you expect 60-40 to be 20, but in this case, you are getting 5 because in your machine each integer occupies 4 bytes or 32 bits.

So you can think of it like this: The first integer at 40 takes 4 places, so the next integer is at 44, then 48, then 52. Thus when getting the difference of memory locations, the program takes each 4 byte block as 1 block and there is a difference of 5 blocks between 40 and 60.

In Pointer math, this can be obtained like abs(mem_location1 - mem_location2)/sizeof(int) (i.e. no. of bytes occupied by an integer).

HTH. :)